# For any odd integer $x,y$, $(x^2+2) \nmid (y^2+4)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quadratics and divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233354/quadratics-and-divisibility)

Prove that for any odd integers $x$ and $y$, we have $(x^2+2) \nmid (y^2+4)$

Comment: Seems identical to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233354/quadratics-and-divisibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x$ is odd, then $x^2+2\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, so $x^2+2$ must have a prime divisor $p$ of the form $4k+3$.

If $x^2+2$ divides $y^2+4$, then $y^2+4\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, or equivalently $y^2\equiv -4\pmod{p}$. Let $w$ be the inverse of $2$ modulo $p$. Then $w^2y^2\equiv -4w^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, and therefore
$$(wy)^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}.$$
This is impossible, since that would mean that $-1$ is a quadratic residue of $p$. But it is a standard theorem that if $p$ is of the shape $4k+3$, then $-1$ is **not** a quadratic residue of $p$.